# RShiny box background color doesn't display as coded

Tags: html, css, r

I'm building UI for a RShiny app but for some unknown reason, the background color of box in the fluidRow doesn't show black as coded. I even added some HTML code to force the box color to be black and it still didn't work.
Here is the code that I wrote. Wonder if anyone could figure out what caused this issue?

```
fluidRow(
              box(width=12,height = 220, background = 'black',
                  sliderInput("slider_fia_prod", "Issue year:", fia_start_yr, fia_end_yr, value=c(fia_start_yr,fia_end_yr), width = '100%'),
                box(width=10, height = 90, background = 'black', 
                    div(plotlyOutput("fia_general_hor_bar"), align = "center")),
                box(width=1, height = 90, background = 'black',
                    div(checkboxGroupInput('by_mva_type', label = 'By MVA Type', choices = list('MVA' = 'A', 'Non-MVA' = 'B'), selected = c('A','B')), 
                        style = "font-size: 12px; padding: 0px", align = "left")),
                box(width=1, height = 90, background = 'black',
                    div(checkboxGroupInput('by_gmwb_rider', label = 'By GMWB Rider', choices = list('GMWB' = 'G', 'Non-GMWB' = 'N'), selected = c('N', 'G')), 
                        style = "font-size: 12px; padding: 0px", align = "left"))),
              tags$style(HTML(".box.box-solid.box-primary>.box-header {color:#fff;background:#000000}
                             .box.box-solid.box-primary{border-bottom-color:#000000;
                                                        border-left-color:#000000;
                                                        border-right-color:#000000;
                                                        border-top-color:#000000;}

                            ")))
```

Much Thanks!